# Windows recovery (fat32) image clone with clonezilla on different filesystem type (ntfs/ext2/ext3/ext4/)

Tags: partitioning, clonezilla

my question is very straightforward. I'm going to follow [this clonezilla step-by-step example](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) to save a Windows Vista Recovery partition (fat32). In the guide it's not mentioned if the image can be saved to a disk with a different filesystem (ext2, ext3, ext4, ntfs...) than fat32. Would that give problems in restoring the image?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which file system you store the image to. The image is a file, containing all the information from the original file system. This can be moved around, to different file systems, without any problem.

In fact, FAT32 would probably be a bad choice for storing images, as it do not support large files (maximum 4GiB), and has a rather dated design. With clonezilla, the size limitation will not matter, as clonezilla by default splits the image into multiple smaller chunks.

So save the image to whatever filesystem you want.

Comment: In fact, Clonezilla will save an image as small chunks. Il will work with FAT32.

Comment: Good point - the remark was more in general; VFAT is a dated file system, and has some annoying limitations today.